# Sorting the Age Groups (Class Function)

Tags: qlikview

In my QlikView app I made the age groups with the following expression (it is defined dimension actually)

```
=Replace(Aggr(Class(Count(Surname), 10), Age), '<= x <', ' - ')
```

The groups are calculated properly, however, I have problems with sorting the groups from the smallest to the highest one. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you say that groups are calculated properly, I suppose that you mean your dimension is 0 - 10, 10 - 20...
But the value of each group is wrong.

Try something like this : `=Replace(Class(Age, 10), '<= x <', ' - ')`

Or better :

```
=if(isnull(Age),<Null>,subfield(class(Age, 10),' ',1) &  ' - ' & (num(subfield(class(Age, 10),' ',5))-1))
```

This one handle Null and make better groups.
Class fonction return "0 <= x < 10" which should be translate 0-9 instead of 0 - 10.

Subfield(X, ' ', Y) split X by space and return the Y part.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with sorting the dimension by text.